# In Oracle selection from two tables, is the relative position of WHERE statements relevant for performance?

Tags: oracle, where-clause, query-performance

I have this homework to do and too much time on my hands, so I want the answer to be perfect instead of just correct. It is all theoretical with no real database behind it. I wondered, whether it would make a performance difference to switch position of WHERE statements as follows:

Order is a table of orders with an order number as primary key. Customer is a table of customers with customer number Cno as primary key. Cno is foreign key in table Order. My task is to formulate a select statement that gives me all the orders for customers named 'Meier', Name is a data column of the customer table.

My first idea is to connect the tables with the foreign key and filter with the name:

```
SELECT O.*
FROM Order O, Customer C
WHERE O.Cno = C.Cno
AND C.Name = 'Meier';
```

I visualize this statement to make a LARGE table with all customer and order data and then to filter with the name.

Then I had the idea I might make the intermediate 'table' smaller to win some performance, so I thought I might reduce the amount of customers to fetch orders for first. I thought of this:

```
SELECT O.*
FROM Customer C, Order O
WHERE C.Name = 'Meier'
AND O.Cno = C.Cno;
```

Now I 'see' that imaginary intermediate table to only include orders for customer 'Meier' and to not to be so large any more.

Then again, I thought Oracle probably optimizes all of this away on its own, so I don't need to worry about it.

Would there be a difference in the performance of these queries, just because the sequence of two where-clause statements is reversed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The order doesn't matter because Oracle's optimizer will look at all the WHERE clauses and figure out the most efficient way to satisfy that query.

You may also consider to have your table statistics up-to-date, because the optimizer tend to use them a lot.

Comment: Thank you.

I will remember about the statistics, if ever I have a real Oracle database on my hands. This is just play pretend with homework.

Answer (score 2):

You may also do something like

```
SELECT O.*
FROM (select Cno from Customer where Name = 'Meier') C, Order O
WHERE O.Cno = C.Cno;
```

99,99% the way of execution will be the, same but you can influence it with hints. For example

```
SELECT O.*
FROM (select /*+ materialize */ Cno from Customer where Name = 'Meier') C, Order O
WHERE O.Cno = C.Cno;
```

will first subset customer into a temporary table and next join it with order. When you have more than 2 tables you can use ORDERED hint.

```
SELECT /*+ ORDERED */ O.*
FROM Customer C, Order O, Some_other_table T
WHERE C.Name = 'Meier'
AND O.Cno = C.Cno
AND O.Cno = T.Cno;
```

will always first join Customer to Order and next the result to Some_other_tables regardless of statistics, which can sometimes be stale.

Comment: Thank you very much for mentioning these additional possibilities. As I am no 'SQL native speaker' and databases are becoming more and more clever at optimization, I presume the database is better at it than I am. However, I will remember these as a last resort, if ever something really does not work 'automagically'.